# Unity FPS Controller camera only moves when mouse movement stops

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using unity FPSController asset, here's the code for actually moving the camera called in `LateUpdate()` method.

```
private void CameraRotation()
{
    // if there is an input
    if (_input.look.sqrMagnitude >= _threshold)
    {
        //Don't multiply mouse input by Time.deltaTime
        float deltaTimeMultiplier = IsCurrentDeviceMouse ? 1.0f : Time.deltaTime;
            
        _cinemachineTargetPitch += _input.look.y * RotationSpeed * deltaTimeMultiplier;
        _rotationVelocity = _input.look.x * RotationSpeed * deltaTimeMultiplier;

        // clamp our pitch rotation
        _cinemachineTargetPitch = ClampAngle(_cinemachineTargetPitch, BottomClamp, TopClamp);

        // Update Cinemachine camera target pitch
        CinemachineCameraTarget.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(_cinemachineTargetPitch, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        // rotate the player left and right
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * _rotationVelocity);
    }
}
```

At first, I thought I was just having FPS issues, but the game is completely smooth when the camera is not moving, as soon as movement starts, the camera is extremely jittery. further testing it feels like the camera only moves when I stop moving my mouse. Like it knows where it *should* be but doesn't get there smoothly, just gets there when you're done inputting your movement. I've tried lowering the rotation speed variable to make sure its not a sensitivity thing. Same problem.

Comment: I think we will need a little more information. 
Do you have a rigidbody and collider attached to the camera? 
What update Loop are you using? Update() or FixedUpdate()
Are you moving the camera at all or just rotating?

I personally have never used the default FPS controller, so I cannot speak from experience, but I can say that there are a hundred ways to make look rotation work and none of them should cause jitters. if you are new, I would recommend having a look at this:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc rather than diving into a control using cinemachine from the get go.